# Catch event product click in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, google-analytics

I am implementing gtm and I want to added data layer when user click on product from catalog, search result or related product. Data layer will be like this

> {   "data": {
>       "action": "category",
>       "product": {
>         "sku": "product sku",
>         "name": "product name"
>       }   } }

Is there any way how can I catch product click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you need to use the following event : catalog_controller_product_view

Comment: This event is working for my case. Thanks sami23

Comment: @Randy ur welcome . Happy for you ;)